# Auto select first item of Comboxbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox that binding a property of ViewModel.

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding UserCollection}"   SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="UserName"   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedUser}"       />
```

I want to select auto first item of it when it have items.

I use `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` and `SelectedIndex="0"` but don't select items.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add your binding property mode as two way

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding UserCollection}"    DisplayMemberPath="UserName"   SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Id}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks , I use this, but don't select.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue` :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserCollection}"  
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"     
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          DisplayMemberPath="UserName"  
 />
```

Then set your `SelectedUser` to the first item of your list (if it's not already set):

```
SelectedUser = UserCollection[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. I can set `SelectedValue` for first item of collection in viewmodel, but i want to set it in xaml. It is possible to set it.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to set both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex`. when you set `SelectedItem` in XAML then you have to change `SelectedUser` in view-model to tell the `ComboBox` which item to select.